# Replacing a part of string in a for loop with a number of loops done

Tags: python, string, for-loop, xpath

How can I change a certain part of a string with the number of loops I have done?

I am scraping data from a website using Chromedriver (find_element_by_xpath). I see the problem occurs when for loop count exceeds 10.
Until *count* reaches 10 it has been able to replace /tr[1] with /tr[2] and so on but as soon as the double digits come along things get complicated.

```
count = 0
for i in range(0, 21):
    count += 1
    string[65] = str(count)
    string = ''.join(string)
    print(string)
    string = list(string)

The output is:
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[110]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1210]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[13210]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[143210]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1543210]/td[2]


And what I expect output to be is:
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
string = "//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"
all_list = [string[:65]+str(i+1)+string[66:] for i in range(0,15)]
print(*all_list, sep='\n')
```

**Output** :

```
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]
//*[@id='teams_wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]
```

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042214/changing-a-looping-string-inside-for-loop